# Spring security on cross platform in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

How to configure spring security on cross-platform, for example I have two application one is server side where all the java code and spring security part I am doing and other client side where all angular js and html files present.

I want to integrate my custom login page which is present at client side with Spring security how can I achieve that, following is my code for Spring security.

```
   public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/assests/**", "/app/**",
                        "/**/*.js", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.gif", "#/index.html", "/home",).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
          .and()
          .addFilterBefore(new AppCORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable();   
}
}
```

and this is My CORS filter.

```
public class AppCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String ALLOWED_ORIGINS = "*";
    private static final String ALLOWED_HTTP_HEADERS = "accept, x-requested-with, access-control-allow-origin,Content-Type,authorization";
    private static final String ALLOWED_HTTP_METHODS = "POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE";

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        //String headerValue = request.getHeaders("Access-Control-Request-Headers"); 
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGINS);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_HTTP_METHODS);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ALLOWED_HTTP_HEADERS);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            try {
                response.getWriter().print("OK");
                response.getWriter().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can share security session between your services by using Redis. Read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-redis) documentation. You can also find an example of it from [this link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_resource_server_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_iii).

Comment: Thanks @furkan3ayaktar I appreciate you response, is there way to do this other than Redis server?

Comment: Probably many options available for this but I used the Redis and oAuth2 solutions. If you do not want to use redis server, maybe you can use oAuth2 support of spring with your app. However, it could be more complex than Redis solution.

Comment: Yes, it looks like very complex with oAuth2, thanks for your response.